# Hide Custom Applications from Task Manager

Tags: .net, vb.net, process, taskmanager

I wanted to try create a multi moniter program like this.

http://www.docs.kr/m/post/entry/Download-Shock-4Way-en

So this basically provides 4 virtual screens you could swap. I believe that the program functions by hiding all the processes for each screen whenever you swap the screen.

So when you swap to another screen, it would hide processes from the original screen then show processes from the new screen.

I worked out how to hide a process and to make it show up again however I don't know how to call all the applications to hide them.

I tried to use the `Process.GetProcesses` method to get an array of applications to hide but that brings all the processes like *svchost.exe*, *dvm.exe* and all those processes that run on the background.

For example, if I have Chrome on, when I call `Process.GetProcesses`, it would not only call *chrome.exe* but also all the other processes which are running on the background.

Can anyone recommend a good way to only call the application's process that are visible?

PS. Like I said, I'm not making this program to harm anyone.

Comment: You probably mean "Window Manager", not "Task Manager".  Asking how to hide things from the Task Manager will probably have people accusing you of writing malware or viruses.

Comment: Oh I didn't know exactly what the name of it was so I just blatantly called it task manager. Thanks

Comment: @D_Pain Just so we're clear: you're talking about this, right? http://images.pcworld.com/images/article/2011/04/1_taskmanager-5160946.jpg

Comment: Yes, thats was what I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can't completely hide a running process from an end user. And you really shouldn't develop software hoping you could.

Think about it: you're an administrator, there's a process that is consuming lots of resources and yet you can't access it to kill it because the developer made that impossible. That would be a huge problem.

Even the least decent operating system should always give the end user the possibility to display running processes. Always.

**EDIT:**

I believe that back in Windows XP it was possible to intercept and alter the list of active processes. You had to write a kernel-mode rootkit presented as a device driver to do so (I'm not too familiar with the procedure).

Of course that was a hack and a way for malware to cause lots of headaches to users. The improved Vista kernel made it much, MUCH harder to do the same on this version and subsequent versions of Windows.

So again, there is no supported way to do what you want. And even if there was, I don't think it could be done within the boundaries of the .NET runtime.

Comment: I mean even if you can hide it from the task manager application tab, you can still access it from the process tab. In addition, I was going to add a function to show the hidden process again.

Comment: @D_Pain I'm afraid the answer is still the same. At best, you could have multiple threads in your app acting as "hidden" processes, but the app process itself would still appear. You have no control over that.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder how that program works then.. Thanks for the help:)

Comment: @D_Pain I would believe that it works at a much lower OS level than pure .NET would allow.

Comment: If you're trying to target 64-bit machines above Windows XP, forget about it, the only solution you might find online some old crappy source that may possible do the job, but pay attention, you can't really remove your process from the process listing, only a rootkit will get that far, though many codes i saw in the past, all had their glitches and sometimes might not even work. I'm talking <2012
You can only TRY to hide it from Task Manager itself, but it would require far too many API calls, and Learning SendMessage between windows, it's a long road, below Vista it's definetely possible.

Comment: Above vista, i don't know if Microsoft patched that security hole in the past two years or so, so, you can try to search google, there's plenty, if none of them work above Windows XP, (test only on 32-bit, remember that.) you're out of luck. That's the far-away .net can go. Even to this day idk any rootkits that do that job that good, but, that's me, i'm sure they exist.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe that the program functions by hiding all the processes for each screen whenever you swap the screen.

No, these programs work by creating additional desktops. A *desktop* is a Windows object. I do not fully understand its features but it seems to be an independent space for windows. Only one desktop can be visible at a time. See [CreateDesktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Hiding windows is extremely fragile. You'll break assumptions that other programs make.